# (VBA) button in a cell, msgbox the cell's row and column

Tags: vba, excel

[image]
I am writing a VBA that would :
Once, I click a button in the cell, extract the location of the cell(i.e. if row is 2 and column is 1, 21) so that I can use it to delete the button
*the button is filling the entire cell

I tried using

> ```
>   c = ActiveCell.Column & ActiveCell.Row
>   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Btn" & c).Select
>   Selection.Delete
> ```

but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I see only text in the cells. Are there buttons there?

Comment: Do the button names have a space character before the numeric portion?

Comment: sorry I edited the post

Comment: no it doesn't its like "btn11"

Comment: If the user clicks a button in a cell, does that cell get selected?

Comment: no, the button gets activated:)

Comment: Is the button a Form Control and have you assigned a macro to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following routine in a standard code module and assign it as a macro to your buttons:

```
Sub DeleteButton()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Delete

End Sub
```

To assign the above procedure as a macro to all of the buttons on the active sheet, run this procedure:

```
Sub AssignMacroToAllButtons()
    Dim b As Shape
    For Each b In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If b.Type = 8 Then
            b.OnAction = "DeleteButton"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but is there a way to assign the macro to all the buttons without having to do it one by one manually?

Comment: ;P I am not familiar with the site, sorry about that

Comment: @Yong Are you still there? I have written a procedure for you to automate the process of assigning the macro to all of the buttons.

Comment: Yes, struggling to figure this out:)